# Note: The site owner has disabled Google Analytics tracking for your user role

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

Does anyone know what "Note: The site owner has disabled Google Analytics tracking for your user role." means exactly?

So I am running a WordPress website. I inspected through Google Chrome, and I saw "Note: The site owner has disabled Google Analytics tracking for your user role." on the Developer Tools. Does anyone have a guess how I could enable Google Analytics tacking for my user role? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have Analytics settings inside wordpress disabled at the administrator level.

Navigate, i.e., to Insights » Settings of plug in you used for implement Analytics code and then check in the tracking tab or similar based plugin used. You should see a setting like '**Ignore these user roles for tracking**' (and the values like 'Administrator', 'Editor' or other).

It is used to avoid dirtying the data with your visits to the site

Answer (score 3):

If you have monster insights installed, by default it will remove you from google analytics tracking if you are logged in ad editor or admin!

Just try to go to your website with an incognito browser and don't log in of course, theoretically, you should not get this warning!

Comment: You gave me the exact answer I wanted. Thank you!